Unable to locate package percona-xtradb-cluster
I am unable to install the percona xtradb on Amazon aws free tier ubuntu 24.04 LTS, while trying to install same as instructions that are given in this document https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtradb-cluster/8.0/apt.html#prerequisites, but still getting an error that package could not be located.


Firstly, do not post pictures. Copy and paste what you see as text. Secondly, did you successfully perform steps 3, 4, 5, and 6? Add the output of 'apt-cache policy' to the question.

Hi, Same issue here. fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install and all steps ended successfully. Did you found the solution?
